# force:recordDate AccountId is null

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Both v.opportunity.Name and v.opportunity.fields.AccountId.value returns null.

Any reason?

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="similarOpportunities" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="relatedInternshipworksites" type="Object[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="opportunity" type="Opportunity" />
    <aura:attribute name="remoteRecordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="showDialog" type="String" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="acc" type="Account"/>

    <force:recordData aura:id="opportunityService"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetRecord="{!v.opportunity}"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.updateAccount}"
                      layoutType="FULL" />

    <force:recordData aura:id="accountRecord"                  
                      targetRecord="{!v.acc}"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      fields="Name"
                       />


    <lightning:card iconName="custom:custom85" title="{! 'Account for ' + v.opportunity.Name}">
        <div class="slds-p-left--medium slds-p-right--medium">
            <ul class="slds-list--vertical slds-has-dividers--top-space">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.acc}" var="item" indexVar="i">
                    <li class="slds-list__item">                   
                        {!item.Name}
                    </li>
                </aura:iteration>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
({
        updateAccount: function(component, event, helper) {
        alert(component.get("v.opportunity.fields.AccountId.value"));
        var tempRec = component.find("accountRecord");
        tempRec.set("v.recordId", component.get("v.opportunity.AccountId"));
        tempRec.reloadRecord();
    }
})
```

Comment: your question is not clear, and it is not clear from your code what you are doing and what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I am trying to get the Account record by passing the AccountId using force:recordData without apex call. I am not even getting the AccountId from Opportunity record, it returns as null.

Comment: I do not think you can do `opportunity.fields.AccountId` - should be `opportunity.AccountId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opportunity object is not supported with Lightning Data Service.

Check [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm) link for the list of objects that are supported.